# Does this mean the DoD is listening to my D-Link Router?

Tags: ip, router

I've only recently been monitoring my router activity and this Incoming listing from a DoD IP address is almost always present. It looks as if they are using the IGMP Protocol to sniff at my domain, but I am not an expert; which is why I am asking the question. Multicasting has NOT been enabled.

[image: Is the Department of Defence Listening To My DLink Router]

Answer (score 2):

No. It very likely does not mean that the DoD is actually connecting to your router.
Many ISPs are using the 22.0.0.0/8 range internally as it is not routed.

The reason why they are doing this this are various.
Some ISPs ran out of IPs in 10.0.0.0/8.
Others want to avoid conflicts with their users running their own equipment in the general private use ranges.

Comment: Please explain a little more if possible. What do you mean by "is not routed"? Also, why is it Incoming...is it some sort of ping request?

Comment: The 22.0.0.0/8 subnet does not have a (public) route announced: https://stat.ripe.net/22.0.0.0-22.255.255.255?sourceapp=ripedb#tabId=routing&routing_routing-status.resource=22.0.0.0-22.255.255.255&routing_routing-status.data_overload_limit=ignore Using DoD networks for this is sadly common practice - especially in mobile networks. I do not know why you get incoming IGMP packets, but I'm not a multicast expert.